# How to group nodes in a networkx python graph based on note attributes?

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx, pyvisa

I am trying to visualise my Linkedin network in the form of a graph where the nodes are people I am connected to and these nodes are to be clustered into the companies they work for. I downloaded my Linkedin network as a csv file and managed to visualise the graph but it looks like a huge globe. If I can group the names by the company and when I click on the node, get the contact details of the person, that would be an amazing visual. I am using pyvis and networkx.

Here is my code:

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv("Connections.csv")

# The dataframe consists of columns First Name, Last Name, #Company, Position and Connected On.

# I added a column called Name which is concat of first and #last names

G_weighted = nx.Graph()
G_weighted.add_edges_from(zip(df["My Network"], df["Name"]))



nx.set_node_attributes(G_weighted, df["Company"], 'Company')
g = Network(height=1080,width=1080, notebook=True)
g.toggle_hide_edges_on_drag(True)
g.barnes_hut()
g.from_nx(G_weighted)
g.show_buttons()
g.show('graph.html')
```

Is there a way to cluster the names into groups based on the company? If so, how do I do it?

I very much love the use of pyvis with networkx because of interactivity options.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but here is how you can achieve it.

Note that pyvis can take a `group` attribute from nodes dataframe and specify a distinct color for each group, as well as a `title` attribute so that when you hover over a node you can view details.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from pyvis.network import Network

# creating test data
node_data = {
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Name": ["Me", "Batman", "Superman", "IronMan"],
    "Company": ["Marvel", "DC", "DC", "Marvel"],
}
edge_data = {"source": [1, 1, 2], "target": [4, 2, 3]}

nodes = pd.DataFrame(node_data)
edges = pd.DataFrame(edge_data)

# getting a group id for each company
groups = nodes.groupby("Company")["id"].apply(list).reset_index()
groups["group"] = groups.index

# finding group id for each node from groups dataframe
nodes = nodes.merge(groups, how="inner", on=["Company"])
nodes["title"] = nodes[["Name", "Company"]].apply(lambda x: f"Name:{x[0]} , Company:{x[1]}", axis=1)

nodes = nodes.drop("id_y", axis=1).set_index("id_x")

# collecting node attributes for network x
node_attrs = nodes.to_dict("index")

# creating a network x graph from dataframes
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edge_data)
nx.set_node_attributes(graph, node_attrs)


pyvis_nt = Network("1000px", "1000px", heading="Graph")
pyvis_nt.from_nx(graph)
pyvis_nt.show('test_graph.html')
```

output:

[image]